# From string in a csv cell to dict

Tags: python

I have a CSV with a column named availableexits. Its data is thus : 'N=1,E=4,S=7'

I want to put it in a dict so it looks like :

```
d = {'N':1, 'E':4,  'S':7}
```

(stop there if you have an answer, below just shows how I do it now)

Currently I read the column data as a string :

```
'N=1,E=4,S=7'
```

then I split it on commas g = d.split(",")

```
g = ['S=1', 'W=3', 'N=4']
```

then i split each of those on the =

```
h = []
for x in g :
    h.append(x.split("="))

#h is now [['N', '1'], ['E', '3'], ['S', '4']]
```

and then cast as a dict

```
e = dict(h) #looks very German

#e is now {'S': '1', 'W': '3', 'N': '4'}
```

I just cast the value to an int when I use it.

I have a feeling I am a horrible person for doing it this way. Whats a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use comprehensions:

```
s='N=1,E=4,S=7'
dict(t.split('=') for t in s.split(','))
```

You can take this further to make the values `ints`:

```
dict((a,int(b)) for a,b in (t.split('=') for t in s.split(',')))
```

Comment: very slick, thank you. j = dict([t.split("=") for t in raw.split(",")]) works and is much prettier (cleaner too imo). Was hoping there was something like a list(formattingString)=>dict method somewhere.